# cakephp seo links with Apache rewritemap

Tags: cakephp

I am new to CakePHP and intereted in creating seo-link.
the details are saved in database like

```
id | seoname | seotitle | link | seolink | rank | active
```

I want to use seolink in my website and want that this should be redirected to normal link before the CakePHP's index.php get the request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to look into is [routes](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/development/routing.html). This won't require any further Apache configuration once you have CakePHP setup and working with the default `/controller/action` setup.

Read the manual and update your question with specific URL requests you need if you're still stuck.